# Prove by mathematical induction that $n^4 − n^3 + n^2 − n$ is divisible by $2$ for all positive integers $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

So I've done the base case with $n = 1$ and the general case of $k^4 − k^3 + k^2 − k = 2m$ but I can't seem to find a way to manipulate $(k+1)^4 − (k+1)^3 + (k+1)^2 − (k+1)$ in a manner such that I can substitute in the $2m$. Any help?

Comment: Alternatively, note that $$n^4-n^3+n^2-n=n(n^3-n^2+n-1)$$ and exactly one of $n$ and $n^3-n^2+n-1$ is even...

Comment: Note: It's probably easier to prove this directly. If $n$ is even, you get even-even+even-even = even, and if $n$ is odd, you get odd-odd+odd-odd = even.

Comment: Hmmm. Yeah, I completely get it logically. J was just wondering if there was a way to somehow fit the number 2 into the proof of divisibility. Thanks.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Indeed. I sigh whenever I see this kind of problem with instructions to use induction.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Our teacher just cleared it out. It doesn't require induction; the textbook isn't very reliable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hidden induction (almost directly):

$$n^4-n^3+n^2-n=n^3(n-1)+n(n-1)=n(n^2+1)(n-1)$$

and since either $\;n\;$ or $\;n-1\;$ is even...

Comment: actually $n(n-1)(n^2+1)$

Comment: Though I think the answer solves the problem, but why is is inductive?

Comment: @Henry Good catch, thanks. Edited.

Comment: @dEmigOd The "hidden" induction is, in this case, to prove that either $\;n\;$ or $\;n-1\;$ is even. It is basically ridiculously trivial, but formally it must be stated.

Comment: Long time no see, my friend !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  Mon cher ami! I've been pretty busy and haven't been around a lot. Nice to see you again.

Answer (score 2):

Mod 2, $n$ takes only the two values 0 and 1 and so $n^k\equiv n\;[2]$. Hence

$$n^4-n^3+n^2-n\equiv n-n+n-n=0\;[2]$$

Answer (score 2):

Express $(k+1)^4 − (k+1)^3 + (k+1)^2 − (k+1)$ in terms of $k^4 - k^3 + k - k$.

$(k+1)^4 − (k+1)^3 + (k+1)^2 − (k+1)=$

$k^4 + (4k^3 + 6k^2 + 4k+1) - k^3 -(3k^2 + 3k + 1) + k^2 + (2k + 1) - k - (1) =$

$(k^4 - k^3 +k^2 - k) + (4k^3 + 6k^2 + 4k) -(3k^2 + 3k) + (1-1+1-1) =$

$(k^4 - k^3 + k^2 - k) +(4k^3 + 6k^2 + 4k) - (3k^2 + 3k)$.

As $k^4 - k^3 + k^2 -k$ is even and $4k^3 + 6k^2 + 4k$ is even then this is even if and only if $3k^2 + 3k$ is even.

And we prove $3k^2 + 3k$ is even the exact same process.

Base case: $k = 0$ then $3k^2 + 3k = 0$ is even.

Induction: Assume $3k^2 + 3k$ is even.

Express $3(k+1)^2 + 3(k+1)$ in terms of $3k^2 + 3k$.

$3(k+1)^2 + 3(k+1) = 3k^2 +(6k +3) + 3k + (3) = (3k^2 + 3k) + (6k + 6)$

And as both $(3k^2 + 3k)$ and $(6k+6)$ are both even, so is $(3k^2 + 3k) + (6k + 6)$

Answer (score 1):

## Claim

> $n^4 − n^3 + n^2 − n$ is even for $n=1,2,\cdots.$

## An Inductive Proof

Let $n=1$. Then $n^4 − n^3 + n^2 − n=0$,which is even. Thus, the claim holds for $n=1.$ Assume that the claim holds for $n=k$,namely, $k^4 − k^3 + k^2 − k$ is even. Then \begin{align*} (k+1)^4 − (k+1)^3 + (k+1)^2 − (k+1)=(k^4 − k^3 + k^2 − k)+4k^3+3k(k+1).\end{align*}

Here is a sum of three even numbers. Therefore, it is even as well, which implies that the claim also holds for $n=k+1$. As a result, by the inductive principle, the claim holds for all $n$. The proof is completed.